# Export and import, only new and updated WordPress data

Tags: database, staging

I'm trying to create a cohesive workflow for the WordPress theme and content that runs our company's site. Recently I setup a staging & Production environment with WPEngine and a local environment using local.

Everything works pretty well, I make changes locally, push to staging and then when everything is good to go, copy the environment using WPEngine's copy to production.

However, things get funky when we have other users who need to do on the fly blog posts, or small edits to a post/page. I can't just import those changes into what I am currently doing locally, and if I am making a new page locally (I use divi and create new layouts for new pages) and try to import from WPEngine to local, it just overwrites anything I have done.

**Is there a way to export and import post/page data that has been updated only?**

Comment: Can you phrase this in a way that makes it specific and factual? This isn't a forum/discussion board and you need to be able to mark an answer as the correct answer, not just a compilation of responses/discussion. _All people with this question need to be able to see the answer you chose as correct and it be correct for them too._

Comment: @TomJNowell hopefully the edits help.

Comment: I believe it can be refined further if you include that you want posts/pages that were updated after a specific date, you could even split into 2 steps each a questions, one for how to find the posts/pages, and another for how to export a list of known posts pages. There's a very high chance one of those has already been asked and has a great answer, and 2x the opportunity to gain reputation points and views. Likewise if you're specific about the format you want that data in, CSV/SQL/etc